# How to make words starting with AB- clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

Here is some basic HTML:

```
<p>Here is a reference: AB-AAA111</p>
<p>Here is a reference: AB-BBB222</p>
<p>Here is a reference: AB-CCC333, AB-DDD444</p>
<p>Here is a reference: AB-EEE555</p>
```

As you can see, each paragraph contains a reference beginning with AB-

End goal: Using JS / jQuery inside Geasemonkey, make each AB- reference clickable. Eg:

```
<p>Here is a reference: <a href="localhost/AAA111"> AB-AAA111 </a> </p>
```

I know how to use Regex to pick out words beginning with AB-  /AB-\w+/gi  and I know how to assign variables and replace specific parts of strings.

What I can't figure out is how to sew it all together in this instance?

Comment: They all have a hyphen as a commonality. It can very easily be done to explode the string and just grab everything after the hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it by a simple regex, you could use this one:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
  .replace(/\bAB-(\w+)/g, '<a href="http://localhost/$1">$&</a>');
```

However, be aware that just replacing strings in an HTML document is always a very bad idea. Imagine there could be for example some class name like `<div class="AB-123" id="abc">`. This approach would break the entire site. Do not use it on sites you do not have under your own control.

Instead try to parse text nodes only. `document` gives you the `evaluate` method for working on particular nodes. You can search for all text nodes as well, e.g.:

```
let nodes = document.evaluate('//text()[contains(.,"AB-")]', document,
  null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
```

This will give you a list of nodes which can be iterated by `nodes.iterateNext()`. The disadvantage is that parsing for hypertexts like `AB-<b>123</b>` becomes very hard.

Answer (score -1):

You wouldn't really need to use Regex

```
inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  var p = inputs[i].innerHTML.substring(21);

  if(p.startsWith("AB")) {
    inputs[i].innerHTML = "<a href='*'>" + p;
    inputs[i].innerHTML += "</a>";
  }
}
```

Just trim the beginning part of the string that does not include the AB... sequence. All you need to do after that is check if the beginning starts with AB and modify the innerHTML of those elements.

If you wanted to use regex for that portion use something like this

```
var re = new RegExp("^AB");
var match = re.test("AB");
```

To see if it starts with that sequence.

I'm sure there's probably a more elaborate solution to adding  tags to those items but this is simple and works.

Hope this helps, cheers